# Synchronous print in Node.js using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, synchronous, puppeteer

I am trying to write synchronous code in Node.js.

```
function func1(fn) { 
  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
  var If = require('If');
  var async = require("async");

  (async () => {


    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // Open page.
    await page.goto("https://www.google.com/");

  })();
  fn();
}

func1(function(){ 
  console.log('world');
});
```

I want the Google page to open first, and when I close it, the program should print: `world`.

Answer (score 1):

Call your `fn` in the callback for the [disconnected](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-disconnected) Puppeteer event.
The code below works fine for me:

```
function func1(fn) {
  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

  (async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // Open page.
    await page.goto("https://www.google.com/");

    browser.on('disconnected', () => {
      fn();
    });

  })();

}

func1(function(){
  console.log('world');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `func1` asynchronous, and then you can [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) your inner anonymous asynchronous function:

```
async function func1 (fn) {
  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
  var If          = require('If');
  var async       = require('async');

  await (async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page    = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://www.google.com/');
  })();

  fn();
}

func1(function () {
  console.log('world');
});
```